# Disable an IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibaction

I've created an IBAction from a button on the storyboard. After it is clicked, I want to disable it so its no longer functional. How can I do this?

```
 @IBAction func b1(sender: AnyObject) {
    displayLabel(1)
}
```

Comment: All actions are linked to specific controls. So why don't you try to disable related control. I mean `userInteractionEnabled = false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outlet for your button and set its enabled property to false in your b1 func. Say your outlet is "button1":

```
    button1.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Taverne is right about disabling button. But from the line

```
button.enabled = false
```

will make button dark greyed out. And user clearly see that it is not tappable or clickable.

But if we use this line:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Then button UI will not change and user thinks that it is tappable. But related action event will not called.

In both case action will not called but the look of button will matter here.

Code will suppose to be like:

```
@IBAction func b1(sender: AnyObject) {
        var view = UIView()
        view = sender as UIView
        view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the button instance in that function as `sender` (`AnyObject`).
You need to convert it to `UIButton` and set it's `userInteractionEnabled` or `enabled` property to `false`.

```
@IBAction func b1(sender: AnyObject)
{
    displayLabel(1)
    var button = sender as UIButton;
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it using:

```
@IBAction func b1(sender: UIButton)
{
    displayLabel(1)
    sender.enabled = false;
}
```